# Auto dealers database

Tags: data-request, address, cars

Where can I find an auto dealer database?

Format database: Dealer name, address, brand, phone, website, and more other information. If possible, the worldwide. If it is impossible for the world, I will be glad and individual countries (interested in any of the countries).

I can parse results from website or database XML, but I don't know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) (OSM), which has the `shop=car` tag:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:shop%3Dcar

you can use this browser tool to refine the query

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/USa

[image]

and bulk downloads are described many places on this site and others